# How to render to offscreen buffer using ClanLib

Tags: c++

I'd like to modify sprite on the fly with ClanLib however I can't find a way to retrieve a CL_GraphicContext from a CL_Sprite object. How should it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this can be done the following way, using classes `CL_FrameBuffer` and `CL_Texture`:

```
CL_FrameBuffer fb(gc);
CL_Texture texture(gc, symbol_width, symbol_height, cl_rgb8);
fb.attach_color_buffer(0, texture);
gc.set_frame_buffer(fb);
gc.clear(CL_Colorf::white);
```